# How to use the Kiwi unit testing library within an OSX application?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, unit-testing

I have tried following the Kiwi tutorial [online](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Guide%3a-Up-and-Running-with-Kiwi) and haven't managed to get further than the end of Step 5. Running a test at the end of Step 5 does not succeed for me, but fails with `ld: library not found for -lKiwi`

When I start from scratch with an OSX application, the same thing happens. When I start with an iOS application, everything works fine, as presented in the tutorial.

Therefore, I believe there is a different step that needs to be taken in order to include the Kiwi testing framework into a OSX application, not just what is presented in the tutorial.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seams that it works in xcode 4.3 but it is not officially supported and does not work for 32bits.
Take a look here: https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/issues/86

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get it set up is with CocoaPods to install `Kiwi/XCTest`.

The `Podfile` would look something like this:

```
platform :osx, '10.8'

target 'MacApp', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'AFNetworking'
end

target 'MacAppTests', :exclusive => true do
    pod 'Kiwi/XCTest'
end
```

There's a GitHub sample app here: https://github.com/shepting/kiwi-mac-demo